2023 tues core 2 MK 3 AL frame. Are there any known good drop in replacement headsets?
ACROS AZX-257 in my Tues Core 2 is on its second bottom bearing and first compression ring. Due to the cost/time of getting parts and the unreliability of the headset, I would like to replace it with a higher quality alternative. Does anyone have any recommendations for an ideally drop in replacement headset?

Hi, welcome to bicycles.  I'm afraid that recommendation questions are off-topic, but if you can formulate a question that can help you evaluate types of headsets or certain characteristics, that might be okay.

Using one of those little plastic mudguards keeps mud and water off the bottom bearing and extends its life. Cover the top and bottom of the bearing cartridge in thick marine/waterproof grease when installing and re-do every few months to further aid weatherproofing.

@Noise That guard won't help the general unreliability of these headsets. Everything i have read online shows that people have issues with this headset all the time and it often doesn't last a full season such as in my case. A mud guard also wouldn't help with the compression fitting wearing out. I will be purchasing one soon to protect both my eyes and the bearings though.

It comes down to if the sealing or the shocks kill it. If your headset is poorly sealed and the bearings corrode/develop pitting, the following Cane Creek Series 40 parts should match your bike:
Cane Creek ZS49/28.6 upper BAA0078K.
Cane Creek ZS56/30 lower BAA0089K - you can just replace the lower cup if the upper isn't giving you grief.
If you're doing downhill-type stuff on your bike and the bearings develop play or balls crack, you might alternatively look at a DH-specific headset: the FSA The Big Fat Pig 1.5R (it's really called that).
The SHIS headset specs are in cursive, any other headset with the same specs will also fit. Sadly, Hope doesn't make the lower cup you need, which is what I would recommend as a knee-jerk response to headset trouble. In fact I doubt you will find any high-end bottom cups that mate an oversized head tube to a 1 1/8" steerer. Cane Creek Series 40 should be miles better sealed and longer lasting than OEM, though.

thank you! Google was only turning up results saying nothing was compatible. those results were from 2019 though. I will look into the cane creek, i believe their products are of much higher repute. However their product page does not seem to mention steerer tube sizing unless that is included in the ZSxx.  Sadly my issues are in both the top and bottom so i must replace both of them or order just the specific parts i need from acros and pay 40$ in shipping for 15$ in parts.

The number after the slash refers to the steerer tube diameter in mm. It’s different top and bottom to help differentiate upper and lower cups

thank you! those cane creek components indeed worked great and now i know how to find new ones in the future.
